# Has anyone tried to install nginad on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, advertisement-server

I'm trying to configure a nginad server, but the documentation says it needs a CentOS machine.

Has anyone tried to install it on Ubuntu machine?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's for the old version in 2014, there maybe some change now. I just provide what I've done at that time.

Not a native English speaker...^_^

- Download Nginad

  git clone the nginad and put the "upload" folder under you web server's web folder.
- install dependencies
  in the upload folder, call

  `composer.phar self-update
  composer.phar install`
- remove the ".dist" of the php files under config/autoload

  `cd config/autoload
  cp database.local.php.dist database.local.php
  cp delivery.local.php.dist delivery.local.php
  cp email.local.php.dist email.local.php
  cp rtb.config.local.php.dist rtb.config.local.php`
- configure your database connection configuration

  please only do the database related part in [link](https://nginad.atlassian.net/wiki/display/NGIN/Installing+NginAd+MySQL+Database+Server+RDB). It creates all the tables needed by nginad.

  you should have php, mysql environment ready.

  what I've done is:

  `` mysql -u root -p  //login mysql
  create database nginad;
  grant usage on *.* to nginad@`%` identified by 'password';
  grant all privileges on nginad.* to nginad@`%` ;
  flush privileges;
  quit; ``

  and

  `//nginad.sql is the sql download from the nginad website 
  mysql -u nginad -p nginad < nginad.sql`

  at last, configure your nginad connection file (/config/autoload/database.local.php)

  `$dbParams = array(
              'dbname' => 'nginad',
              'user'   => 'root',
              'pass'   => '',
              'host'   => 'localhost',
  );`
- In order to make you Ad request work, you should also change the request domain, please see the public/ad/nginad.js file.
  modify the first line:

  `var adserver_domain = ""`

  set the adserver_domain to your nginad server.
- About the admin password, the nginad has an initial admin account, but I didn't know the password. So I've just modified the sql database....(now it has documentation about the initial account, but I can't remember the url..)

Answer (score 2):

I have not but if you need any information while trying to install it you could click on the support tab on the right side of the official website at http://www.nginad.com

No CentOS specific packages or code is actaully used by NginAd as NginAd is a 100% pure PHP application which runs on multiple PHP runtimes on multiple platforms.

The installation process requires nginx, php-fpm, MySQL and apc which are all available on Ubuntu as well as CentOS.

Comment: Thank you, I've successfully run it in Ubuntu already. I found it hard to get documentation about Nginad. Currently I found the exchange function of NginAd is not working well。

Comment: @Jerrylk were you able to install id completely can you please guide me how can i install it on my CentOs vps?

Comment: @Jerrylk I am trying to install ngniad server on ubuntu can you provide me some insights on this, thank you.

Comment: @Dilip Kumar ,Hi, anything I can help? I've successfully installed it on ubuntu.

Comment: @Jerrylk it's so great of you I have installed all the necessary packages and installed NGIIndad server I have having difficulty in starting the server and providing the domain name. If you can share links or documents which will help in guiding me in the further process. This is my email I'd: Rakesh.dhananjay90@gmail.com. Thank you.

Comment: @DilipKumar I've sent it to your email